# Angular 6 & .Net Core 2 - XSRF token generated but empty when sent back to API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I have a .net core 2.* API with an Angular 6.* application which I am trying to protect against XSRF attacks.

When logging in, we get an auth token,  then we make another call to get a XSRF token.

On the client side we have a HTTP interceptor which appends the token to the header of any subsequent requests made to the API.

The API code looks to be correct and I can see that the response header contains a the XSRF token  however, when ever a subsequent request is made to the API Request.Headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] exists but it is empty.

Can anyone advise me on where I may have gone wrong?

I have been following this example: https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/11/29/asp-net-core-web-api-antiforgery/

**API Controller**

```cs
    [ApiController]
    public class AntiForgeryController : Controller
    {
        private IAntiforgery _antiForgery;
        public AntiForgeryController(IAntiforgery antiForgery)
        {
            _antiForgery = antiForgery;
        }

        [Route("api/antiforgery")]
        [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GenerateAntiForgeryTokens()
        {
            var tokens = _antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
            Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-REQUEST-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = false
            });
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
```

**UI Service method.**

```js
      getAntiForgeryToken(): any {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/antiforgery`).pipe(map(x => {
          return true;
        }));
      }
```

**UI http interceptor.**

```js
    export class AddCsrfHeaderInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            let requestToken = this.getCookieValue('XSRF-REQUEST-TOKEN');
            return next.handle(req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', requestToken)
            }));
        }

        private getCookieValue(cookieName: string) {
            const allCookies = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split('; ');
            for (let i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = allCookies[i];
                if (cookie.startsWith(cookieName + '=')) {
                    return cookie.substring(cookieName.length + 1);
                }
            }
            return '';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with [SecureWebApiCookiesExample](https://github.com/ruidfigueiredo/SecureWebApiCookiesExample) from provided link, it works correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a demo'able version.  It is an application produced by the company that I work for and only internally available.

Comment: You could download the working demo, and check the difference.

Comment: Edward, Your code solution works for me. I was finding problems with implementing the anti forgery token for angular and .net web api combination and your solutions works and that should be an answer for this question